# Create a new column in R spreadsheet with a specific calculation

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have looked for an answer to this on stackexchange but the questions being asked are way more complicated than what I need.

I have a table in R

```
Teacher Name  Usage_in_MINS  Usage Rate
      Kelper             78 
      Kelper             85
       Smith             85
      Kelper             45
       Smith             65
   7th Grade             45
   4th Grade             34
```

How do I get R to create a new column called `Usage Rate`
How do I get this new column to take the values in `Usage_in_MINS` and divide it by 60 for only those classes that are either `Kelper` or `Smith`? What about if I want it to calculate usage rates for `Kelper` and `Smith` and everyone else as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of really good basic tutorials on R out there, and you would really help yourself by checking out one or two of them because your question indicates some significant niavete. :-) Here's one way to do what you'd like, assuming that your data.frame is called "data":

```
data$UsageRate[data$TeacherName %in% c("Kelper", "Smith")] <- 
    data$Usage_in_MINS[data$TeacherName %in% c("Kelper", "Smith")] * 60
```